# Laravel application versioning

Tags: laravel, versioning

I have a question. How do you handle versioning and breaking changes (Especially database changes) in your Laravel applications? Ill try to explain a little why this is an issue for me.

Right now the only real versioning we did in our Laravel application was in the API's. We just used a new version prefix for the api calls and linked them to the correct controller based on the version. (e.g. prefix => v1, controller route => 'Api\V1\FooBarController'. If we had a new version we just made a copy from the old controller and modified it to our liking.

Now our issue. For our next version (v3) we have ALOT of database changes and decided to just make a separate database with a new connection and migrate any needed information over from our old database to the new one. This way we are able to keep everything working for our older API version (v2). But because we have alot of changes in the database we need to change alot in the models too.

Should i also separate my models in different folders with a version prefix? Or im i doing this totally wrong in general? Im a bit lost and would like to hear how you guys handle this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this link helps what you're referring to :
https://medium.com/@juampi92/api-versioning-using-laravels-resources-b1687a6d2c22

Comment: Does your application use version control software? If so, have you considered running several instances of your API at once on different sub domains? TBH, the way you have described things, it doesn't sound very sustainable

Comment: @Spholt We dont use any version control software. And you're correct, it isn't very sustainable. Im looking for a way to set things up to make it sustainable for the future. The only downside is that i can't start clean since I do have to keep supporting our earlier versions. If you could point me into the right direction to setup things properly I would be very grateful. There is alot on the internet but at this point im a bit lost in what solution would be suitable for our case.